# How to link sqlmap with my own script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, unix, sqlmap

I'm currently programming in python :
- a graphical interface
- my own simple client-server based on sockets (also in python).

The main purpose here is to recieve a message (composed of several fields), apply any changes on it, and then send back the message to the client.

What I want to achieve is to link the modification of a field of this message with any script (I Just saw radamsa which could do the job, I still need to test it.
For example the message : John/smith/London would be John/(request by script)/London.

I don't know if it's even possible to use just a part of code of something like sqlmap (or something else, I don't mind), without the whole thing.

I hope I have given enough details, if not, feel free to ask for any  =)

Edit: the use of sqlmap is not mandatory, it's just one of the few fuzzing scripts i was aware of

Comment: Since it's my first post here, i can't justt add a comment. If someone is kind enough to edit that, I would be grateful. Sqlmap doesn't seem to provide code that could be used out of the box. The documentation is very intricated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**
I finally managed to do what I had in mind.
In SQLmap, the "dictionnary" can be found in the "/xml" directory.
By using several "grep" I have been able to follow the flow of creation. Then, to create the global payload, and then split it in real SQL payload